# Imacros script. Extract data from csv file and fill form

Tags: csv, extract, imacros

I have a problem with Imacros scripting. I need to extrapolate data from the file.csv and put it on apposite tabs but the problem is that it seems like Imacros put all data of all columns of the first line in the first tab only.
[Here's link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIrUr.jpg) of a screenshot of my file.csv 
and this is the script:

```
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE file.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 3
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:post_three CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG  POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:source ATTR=ID:htmlSource CONTENT=<a href={{!COL2}}<SP>title="title"<SP>target="_blank">{{!COL3}}</a>text
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:save_button
```

The problem is that in the tag where should be only COL1 imaBasicros put the values of COL2 and COL3 together separated by comma. Basically in COL1 i should get only the number 1, instead i get 1,4,7 and in the next loop i get 2,5,8.
Where could possibly be the error?

PS. 
Somebody suggested me to save the file in txt but nothing changed.

Comment: I had the same problem in the past. My excel variant was european so the csv files where separated by default with ; instead of , . Imacros seems to like only csv files separated with comma. Open your file in notepad and check what separator it's used.

Answer (score 1):

From [Imacros documentation](http://wiki.imacros.net/!DATASOURCE):

*iMacros 7 can use either a comma as CSV separator, or the list separator set in Windows Regional Settings.*

Change your default separator in Imacros options or change it just for your current script:

```
SET !DATASOURCE_DELIMITER ; 
SET !DATASOURCE file.csv
```